# Etymology of Fortasse

Tags: etymology

The word "fortasse" (meaning 'perhaps') looks like it's two words squished together, but I can't find any etymology for it. Does anyone know where fortasse comes from?

Answer (score 7):

It comes from *forte* "perhaps", which seems to be from the ablative of *fors* "chance, luck" (Proto-Indo-European root **bʰr-ti-* 'bearing, case'). That in turn is derived from the same root as *fero* "to bring" (Proto-Indo-European **bʰer-e/o-* 'to carry', De Vaan s.v.).

De Vaan s.v. *fors*:

> PIE **bʰr-ti-* 'bearing, case'? IE cognates: see s.v.*ferō*
>
> The origin of *fortasse* seems to be **forte an sīt/s*, but the phonetics (especially the short final vowel) are unclear.

*Forte an sit* would mean something like "[it is] chance whether that is [so]". Cf. *forsitan, fortassean*.